# Value of Passed-By-Value Struct Does Not Change

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, pass-by-value

I am trying to understand how to pass a struct by reference in order to create a linked list. The method I am using is similar to the example code given below. However, when this code is run, the *tester declared in the main function always stays as NULL. Is the passing of a struct to the addNode() function in this way inappropriate (the compiler does not raise any warnings)?

```
struct test{
  int num;
  struct test *next;
};
void addNode (int num, struct test* tester);

int main (void){
  struct test *tester = null;
  addNode(1, tester);
}

void addNode(int num, struct test* tester){
  struct test *example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  example->num = num;
  if (tester == NULL){
    tester = example;
  } else{
    tester->next = example;
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (tester = NULL)`... doesn't that operator look strange to you?

Comment: C has no notion of pass by reference FYI.  I realize that this is a terminology issue in this case, but passing a copy of a pointer is not pass by reference.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Sorry about that. I fixed the syntax in the example but the problem persists.

Comment: `tester = example;` must cause a compilation error.  You should fix compilation errors before attempting to understand any output. And if this isn't your real code... copy-paste in your real code else you are just wasting time. `null` is also an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're assigning `NULL` to your input.  This:

```
if (tester = NULL)
```

should be

```
if (tester == NULL)
```

Secondly, in that same branch, you assign a new value to `tester`.  However, everything in C is passed by value (copy), so your function receives a copy of a pointer.  Therefore, you are only mutating the function's local copy.  You need another level of indirection:

```
#include <assert.h>

struct test{
  int num;
  struct test *next;
};

void addNode (int num, struct test* tester);

int main (void){
  struct test *tester = NULL;
  addNode(1, &tester);
}

void addNode(int num, struct test** tester){
  / * wrong, check next item */
  assert(tester != NULL);

  struct test example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  example->num = num;
  if (*tester == NULL){
    *tester = example;
  } else{
    (*tester)->next = example;
  }
}
```

Last, `malloc` returns a `void*`, which can implicitly be converted to any other type of pointer.  It does not however return an "instance".  So this is wrong:

```
struct test example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

and should be:

```
struct test *example = malloc(sizeof *example);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `addNode` function the pointer `tester` no longer points to the location pointed by the `tester` in `main`. function and change your function to

```
void addNode(int num, struct test** tester){
    struct test *example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    if (NULL == example )
         exit(0);        // Not enough memory

    example->num = num;  
    if (NULL == *tester)
         *tester = example; 
    else
        (*tester)->next = example;
}
```

Call this function from `main` as `addNode(1, &tester);`. Now `*tester` is an alias for `tester` in `main`.

Comment: Still won't work as he is assigning a new value to a copy of a pointer in that branch.  He needs to pass a `test**`

Comment: @EdS. What would be the best way to get around this problem?

Comment: "...pass a `test**`".  Also, your declaration of `example` is wrong.

Comment: @EdS. Would that mean having `void addNode(int num, struct test** tester)`? If so, how would I call this method?

Comment: @mCode: I just went ahead and posted an answer since none of these hit all of the problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the pointer returned by `malloc` as a struct:

```
struct test example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

Perhaps you wanted to store it as a pointer to struct, so that `example` and `tester` have matching types:

```
struct test* example = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

Then, this will make sense:

```
tester = example;
```